# haskell evaluation $ sign

Tags: haskell, operator-keyword, composition

I am going through 'learn you some haskell' and I have written following application:

```
import System.IO

main = do
    filename <- getLine
    handle <- openFile filename ReadMode
    content <- hGetContents handle
    putStr . unlines . (map isLong) . lines $ content
    hClose handle

isLong :: String -> String
isLong x = if length x > 10 then x ++ " long enough" else x ++ " could be better!"
```

And it works but when I remove "$" between lines and content a compilation fails.

Could you help me understand why this is wrong?

I was thinking that I compose statements with dots and I get a function (String -> IO ()) and I apply it to the "content" but why is "$" needed here?.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The operator (.) has type `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`....  Its first two inputs must be functions.

`lines content`, however, is of type `[String]`, not a function, hence `f . lines content` will fail.  The compiler treats it as

```
f . (lines content)
```

By adding the `($)`, you change the precedence, and it becomes

```
f . lines $ content = (f . lines) $ content
```

which works, because `f` and `lines` are both functions.

Answer (score 0):

The dollar sign in haskell is used for application of a function on a value.

Its backround is, that you do not need complicated parentheses in terms.